# Is it still possible to have cloudflare dns point to free heroku instance?

Tags: heroku, dns, cloudflare

I have a test app hosted at heroku for free, for which I bought a domain `example.com` that is managed through cloudflare, hopefully, to add free ssl after too.

The app is running ok at `example.herokuapp.com`. In heroku's dashboard I added the domains

- `example.com` that gave me a `random-url.heroku.com` dns target in return
- `www.example.com` gave me a `random-url2.heroku.com` in return

I then added two CNAME registries on Cloudflare

- CNAME `example.com` pointing to `random-url.heroku.com`
- CNAME `www.example.com` pointing to `random-url2.heroku.com`

SSL is off in cloudflare to test it out.
Opening example.com in chrome says `This page isn’t working, redirected you too many times`.

Comment: Yes, it is possible and your setup seems to be correct. It seems like something in changing the request hostname from example.herokuapp.com to example.com has caused the origin/heroku server to serve a redirect resulting in a redirect loop. Can you please go to the network tab of the chrome console with "preserve log" checked and capture the Location header(s) that are showing in the redirect loop?

Comment: Gotcha! so that happened when ssl was off but Cloudflare CNAME with "Proxied". It was in a constant loop between http and https nevertheless. I turned off the Proxied (to DNS only) and now it doesn't redirect in loop but it does redirect to https...

Comment: And now who seems to be doing the redirect is "Server: Cowboy", I think heroku...for no apparent reason.

Comment: When Proxy is off a.k.a. "DNS only" cloudflare will use the actual DNS entries you have entered.  The effect of this is that traffic goes directly to your origin server (Heroku) and does not touch cloudflare.  In my opinion there is no reason to disable universal SSL. It does not generally add complication and could possibly resolve your issue. In proxied mode cloudflare is very good and reliable at negotiating and establishing a SSL connection and any Cloudflare issues will usually appear as a secure cloudflare branded page with an error displayed.

Comment: Thanks for you help drussey, the tip about "preserve log" got me through it all, I had some bad code as well as routes that made it redirecto to https, all has been figured out and settings in cloudflare/heroku were ok after all.